# change div class based on id in angular directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using a custom directive in diferent sections of my page. For that i have created a custom simple directive to display a the class of the html div based on id. this is done inside of an ng-repeat.

The html portion is like this:

```
<l-status id="l.status" name="l.name"></l-status>
```

Here is my directive:

```
app.directive("lStatus", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            id: '=',
            name: '='
        },
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "/app/views/status.html"
    }
});
```

in my directive template i have the following:

```
<span ng-if="id === null" class="label label-primary">{{name}}</span>
<span ng-if="id === 1" class="label label-danger">{{name}}</span>
```

This gives me an error. But if i leave the "'ng-if="id === *'" part away i get back the expected result. Unfortunatly without the desired class!

Meybee there is a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using `ng-class` instead.
[Documentation on ng-class here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Basically you do

`<span class="label" ng-class="{'label-primary': id === null, 'label-danger': id === 1}>{{name}}</span>`

Comment: But i would like to define the classes for the specific ids in one place. With your solution i would have to change that code all around my page, which is not a good solution! And i have more than 2 different class as well!

Comment: You use my example in your directive template, that's only one place

Comment: Can i do multiple if else statement in ng-class? If yes how?

Comment: Sure, `ng-class="{'label-primary': id === null || id === 2 }`
Was that what you meant?